Openssl library ARM execution TLS and Incompatible version of OpenSSL Failure
I am trying to run an Application to use http url images(for display) that uses the openssl 1.1.1d version for the Qt Framework on the ARM platoform. I was able to build the openssl 1.1.1d for ARM and load the library into the device, also have set the ld path in the /etc/ld.so.conf.  After all that, I have built and link the sample  Application and it throws the following error
QSslSocket Build  "OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022"
qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL (built with OpenSSL >= 3.x, runtime version is < 3.x)
QSslSocket Version  0
supportsSsl  false

I have also tried moved out the openssl 3.0 libraries to a tmp folder. But still it throws the same error.
However I was able to build the openssl 1.1.1d on x86 and run the sample-Application with success using http url images.
QSslSocket Build  "OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019"
QSslSocket Version  269488207
supportsSsl  true

What is going wrong on the deivce, is it the build steps or the device needs to configure properly? CMAKE for ARM, below the path is shown in the link file for both vars OPENSSL_SSL_LIB, OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIB:
set(SSL_PATH "$ENV{SDKTARGETSYSROOT}/usr/local/lib")
find_library(OPENSSL_SSL_LIB
                NAMES "libssl.so"
                NAMES_PER_DIR
                REQUIRED
                HINTS  ${SSL_PATH}
                PATHS  ${SSL_PATH}
                NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_library(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIB
                NAMES "libcrypto.so"
                NAMES_PER_DIR
                REQUIRED
                HINTS  ${SSL_PATH}
                PATHS  ${SSL_PATH}
                NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/usr/local/lib")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
add_executable(helloworld main.cpp mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.ui resources.qrc)
target_link_libraries(helloworld-image
                      Qt5::Core
                      Qt5::Network
                      Qt5::Widgets
                      ${OPENSSL_SSL_LIB}
                      ${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIB})


I was able to build the openssl 1.1.1d  OpenSSL 1.1.1d is five years old.  A bunch of CVEs have been fixed in the 1.1.1 tree after the release of 1.1.1d, and the entire 1.1.1 tree is now EOL and will not be getting any fixes.  See https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-217/product_id-383/version_id-588006/Openssl-Openssl-1.1.1.html  For just one example, here's one 10.0 vulnerability not fixed in 1.1.1d:  https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2022-2068/
